# Adding Icon on desktop of iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I want to place an icon on the iPhone screen form my application, like placing an icon and if i will touch that icon it will do the desired operation, like opening a sound file or an image.

So  i want to ask is it possible to place an icon on screen through an application and do some events on it.

Regards,
Vishal

Answer (score 4):

You can't do that. The only icon that will appear on the iPhone home screen will be the icon for your application itself.

Edit:

Expanding on the web shortcut idea suggested by Gene, it *might* be possible you achieve what you want by having a web short cut using a specific protocol handler to open your app with a web short cut added to the home screen. Take a look at this article:

http://www.mobileorchard.com/apple-approved-iphone-inter-process-communication/

I believe that would still require the user to add the shortcut though, I don't *think* a third party app can add web shortcuts.

Comment: You could use a UIActivityViewController to do this from the app: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22266930/545599

Answer (score 1):

Andynormancx is correct.  The only exception to this rule (that I know of) is a web shortcut -- within Mobile Safari, you can select "add to home screen", and a shortcut to the bookmarked page will appear on Springboard.  The icon is a partial screenshot of the web page.

I don't know if this would be useful to you, though I suppose you could bookmark a link to a sound file or image.

Answer (score 1):

I found it annoying that google maps cannot be page bookmarked onto the home screen. Here is an almost quick solution:

1. Create a Tiny URL of the target Google Map.  SF Bay Area Traffic is http://maps.google.com/maps?hl=en&ie=UTF8&ll=37.55111,-122.121277&spn=0.810034,1.182404&z=10&layer=t
2. Mail yourself the Tiny URL.
3. Select the URL in the email application.
4. Before Safari realizes that it is a Google Map url,  touch the x on the url line to cancel the transfer to the Google Map App.
5. Touch the + at the bottom of Safari and touch "Add to Home Screen"

Name it appropriately and, there you have it, a Google Map entry  on your home screen.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create an application and under `ApplicationDidLoad` in your `ApplicationViewController.h`
You would type in your code. (If you don't have the SDK, then don't post the question with the tags iPhone-SDK and Cocoa.)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Gene's answer, you may want to set the following meta tags:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="https://path/to/icon.png" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
```