# In UIWebView how integrate "Add bookmark " feature

Tags: objective-c, ios

I want to integrate add book mark like safari in iphone like [image]

here the snapshot of add bookmark feature of safari browser from iPhone i want to add same feature like it
How can i do it ?

Comment: please add image description here :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you will need to add an alertView

```
 sheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Select Account to Delete"
                                      delegate:self
                             cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                        destructiveButtonTitle:@"Delete All Accounts"
                             otherButtonTitles:@"Add bookmark", @"add to reading", @"add to home screen", nil];
  // Show the sheet
  [sheet showInView:self.view];
  [sheet release];
```

that will create a popup view (AKA alertview) as your image shows above.

as for the "Add bookmark" or "add to home" it is slightly more complex, since the API does not provide you with the functions to do so, your best bet will be looking at a webview programatically launch Safari from within your app and give it the URL

read about it here: [iPhone SDK - Add a "Add to Home Screen" button in a UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10836925/iphone-sdk-add-a-add-to-home-screen-button-in-a-uiwebview)

Answer (score 4):

http://xcode4all.wordpress.com/2011/05/25/web-browser-or-how-to-use-the-uiwebview-part-33/

It will be helpful