# Is it possible to create "Add to Home Screen" like feature from another app?

Tags: ios, ios7

Currently "Add to Home Screen" works only with Safari browser. 1. Is it possible to programmatically create "Add to Home Screen" short cut from a custom native iOS app ? 2. Is it possible to make the short cut to launch another app, not the safari app?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit broad a question, but I'll attempt an answer.  Short answer: no.  You cannot add a home screen icon that launches another app from within your app without going through Safari first.  (You can, however, link to another app directly from yours.  See below.)

More intricate answer: if you want to launch another application from your own, and the application supports URL schemas (i.e. `instagram://` for launching Instagram), you will be able to.  Please see [this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html) for the official docs.

The part that may remain unanswered here is whether a UIWebView can create a home screen shortcut from inside another app.  It seems you cannot do this, after a bit of googling.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10836925/iphone-sdk-add-a-add-to-home-screen-button-in-a-uiwebview) explains.